# How to poll python asyncio task status

Tags: python, python-asyncio, gevent

With gevent, I can monitor a long running function like so:

```
    greenlet = gevent.Greenlet(long_running_task, *args, **kwargs)
    greenlet.start()
    while not greenlet.ready():
        send_heartbeat()
        gevent.sleep(heartbeat_interval)
    if greenlet.successful():
        send_success(greenlet.value)
    else:
        send_failure(exception=greenlet.exception)
```

How would I do this with asyncio? I've tried the following but I'm stuck:

```
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async def send_heartbeat(heartbeat_interval=15):
        send_heartbeat()
        asyncio.sleep(heartbeat_interval)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([long_running_task(*args, **kwargs), send_heartbeat()]))
    loop.close()
```

How would I change this to get the intended behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can schedule the long running task with [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) (but not awaiting it). In return you'll get a [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) object that have [`done`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.done) method that is similar to `ready`

```
async def some_job():
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(long_running_task(*args, **kwargs))
    while not future.done():
        await send_heartbeat(heartbeat_interval=15)

    try:
        result = future.result()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # the task has been cancelled
    except Exception:
        # some exception was raised in long running task

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(some_job())
loop.close()
```