# Python, a clean way to check if a task has finished

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.parse_url, url) for url in urls]
await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5)
for (i, task) in zip(urls, tasks):
    result = task.result() if task._state.lower() == 'finished' else []
```

In the code above I use the '_state' property to check if the task has indeed finished and did not timeout.

Is there a cleaner way of doing it? I don't think I'm supposed to access the '_state' property like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226289/how-to-poll-python-asyncio-task-status

Comment: @DroidX86 its the total opposite of what I'm doing. I don't want to ensure futures, I want tasks to timeout after a set period of time

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`task.done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.done) to check whether a task has finished.

Also, `asyncio.wait()` itself returns two sets of tasks: those that have actually finished, and those that haven't, so you can iterate only over the `done` set:

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5)
for t in done:
    ...
```